# Escape a whole dictionary / JSON at once

Tags: python, mysql, json, dictionary

I've build a simple Python API which receives JSON dictionaries with strings and numeric values from the clients.

In order to protect my system and avoid MySQL-Injections I escape the strings when I'm using it f.ex.:

```
jsonInput = request.get_json(force=True, silent=True)  # INPUT FROM HTTP POST REQUEST

# ESCAPING STRING BY STRING
flowerColor = MySQLdb.escape_string(jsonInput['flowerColor'])
flowerSize = MySQLdb.escape_string(jsonInput['flowerSize'])

query = "SELECT * FROM flowers WHERE color='" +  flowerColor + "' AND size='" + flowerSize + "'"
try:
    conn = // CONNECT TO DB
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(query)
    return cursor.fetchall()
except MySQLdb.IntegrityError:
    return False
```

In my opinion it would be way easier, if there is a method to just escape the whole input at once, so every string in the JSON can be used directly after the escape method in a MySQL query. For example:

```
jsonInput = request.get_json(force=True, silent=True)  # INPUT FROM HTTP POST REQUEST

# ESCAPING WHOLE JSON AT ONCE 
escapedJSON = escape_json_at_once(jsonInput) 

query = "SELECT * FROM flowers WHERE color='" +  escapedJSON['flowerColor'] + "' AND size='" + escapedJSON['flowerSize'] + "'"
try:
    // EXECUTE THE QUERY
except MySQLdb.IntegrityError:
    return False

// DO OTHER QUERIES WITH ESCAPED JSON DATA
```

I already found the method `MySQLdb.escape_dict()` but couldn't get it to work also with reading the docs.

Does somebody know a way to escape the whole input at once?

Comment: What do you mean by escape here? In what context do you need to escape the data explicitly? Give some example code.

Comment: Why aren't you using prepared statements/placeholders‽

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, there is indeed a better way

```
jsonInput = request.get_json(force=True, silent=True)  # INPUT FROM HTTP POST REQUEST


query = "SELECT * FROM flowers WHERE color=%s AND size=%s"
try:
    conn = // CONNECT TO DB
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(query, ( jsonInput['flowerColor'],jsonInput['flowerSize']) )
    return cursor.fetchall()
except MySQLdb.IntegrityError:
    return False
```

With this approach you don't need to escape anything at all and it's shorter and neater.

Comment: Thanks! So this way possible SQL-Injection characters like `;` or `'` and `"` in the JSON input file won't be affect anything in my query?

Comment: yes, this is actually safer than string concatenation

Comment: Would be this also safe to use: `query = "SELECT %s FROM %s WHERE %s='%s'" % (parameter, table, key, value)` ?

Comment: that would be illegal! tablenames and column names in the projection cannot be bound as parameters.

Comment: Sorry I just copied my code from a generic function. Of course I'm not using table name and column from the input! `query = "SELECT flowerID FROM flowers WHERE color='%s'" % (flowerColor)`

Comment: yes that would work. You don't need the quotes around %s

Comment: glad to have been of help